# Align an unwrapped text vertically in css

Tags: css

I have some text in an `<a>` tag besides a span with a svg in it with the structure as follows

```
<a>
   <span>
       ...svg here...
   </span>
   Some unwrapped text here
</a>
```

I can't get it to align the, vertically into the `<a>` tag. I tried with `vertical-align`, but I should have `display: inline-block` to both of them.

I can't wrap the text in anything, can't touch the HTML.

[Here is a JsFiddle with the problem](https://jsfiddle.net/7mmcznkr/1/)

How can I vertical align them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is precisely where [flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/flex) comes in handy:

```css
.addthis_button_facebook {
    background: pink;
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 80px;
    padding: 0 8px;
}
```

```html
<a class="addthis_button_facebook at300b" title="Facebook" href="#">
  <span class="at-icon-wrapper" style=" line-height: 32px; height: 32px; width: 32px;">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 32 32" title="Facebook" alt="Facebook" class="at-icon at-icon-facebook" style="width: 32px; height: 32px;">
      <g>
        <path d="M22 5.16c-.406-.054-1.806-.16-3.43-.16-3.4 0-5.733 1.825-5.733 5.17v2.882H9v3.913h3.837V27h4.604V16.965h3.823l.587-3.913h-4.41v-2.5c0-1.123.347-1.903 2.198-1.903H22V5.16z" fill-rule="evenodd"></path>
      </g>
    </svg>
  </span>
  Share
</a>
```

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7mmcznkr/2/

[CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) has a lot more information on flex as well.

Answer (score 1):

Flex is the easiest, but just for fun, here's an alternative way to get a similar result.

```css
a {
  display: table;
  line-height: 32px;
}

a span {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<a class="addthis_button_facebook at300b" title="Facebook" href="#">
  <span class="at-icon-wrapper" style=" line-height: 32px; height: 32px; width: 32px;">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 32 32" title="Facebook" alt="Facebook" class="at-icon at-icon-facebook" style="width: 32px; height: 32px;">
      <g>
        <path d="M22 5.16c-.406-.054-1.806-.16-3.43-.16-3.4 0-5.733 1.825-5.733 5.17v2.882H9v3.913h3.837V27h4.604V16.965h3.823l.587-3.913h-4.41v-2.5c0-1.123.347-1.903 2.198-1.903H22V5.16z" fill-rule="evenodd"></path>
      </g>
    </svg>
  </span>
  Share
</a>
```